# Как изменить значение observable y rxjs

Tags: typescript

```
export class Test
         {
             foo = Observable.of(1); // this.foo при определении будет равна 1
                 constructor(){
                     this.foo.subscribe(val = > console.log(val) // при инициализации класса в консоль выведется 1
                }
         }
```

Если я хочу изменить значение `this.foo` не внутри `subscribe` то как мне это сделать? и отреагирует ли подписчик, который объявлен в конструкторе на изменения?

Answer (score -2):

Привет, тебе нужно использовать немного не это, тебе нужно использовать такую штуку как Rx.Subject()

Эта штука может получать данные извне и является своего рода Observable.
Вкратце:

```
foo = new Subject();

foo.subscribe(val = > console.log(val));

foo.next(1);
foo.next(2);
foo.next(3);
foo.complete();
```